# jquery mobile displays wrong div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I've got 2 stylistic/best practice questions and one "how do I keep THAT from happening" question.

I have a mobile site

```
 <div data-role="page" id="A">
     stuff       
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="B">
     stuff       
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="C">
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <div id="bottombuttondiv" data-role="navbar">
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#pDialog">Show Dialog</a></li>
                  <li><a id="settings" href="javascript:showSettings();" >Settings</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-history="false" data-role="popup" id="pDialog" >
           <div role="main" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
              <p>So what do you want to do?</p>
              <a href="javascript:doThis();" data-role="button" >Do This</a>
              <a href="javascript:doThat();" data-role="button" >Do That</a>
           </div>
        </div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="D">
     <form>
        <button type="submit" onclick="save(this.form)" value="Save" >Save</button>
     </form>
 <div>


 function doThat(){
     $.mobile.changePage( "#D", { transition: "slideup"} ); 
 }


 function save(frm){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url:    "url1",
            data: "JSON data",
            success: function(msg) {
                        $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",
                                url:    "url2",
                                data: "diff JSON data",
                                success: function(msg) {

                                },
                                error: function(msg) {
                                    alert("Oops");
                                }
                         });
             },
            error: function(msg) {
                alert("Oops");
            }
          });
 }
```

This is my first attempt at using jquery mobile.

I have buttons with onclick="someFuction()" in the A and B divs.

someFunction() takes the input from the widgets in the div, displays an alert if something is no good and if everything is ok causes the next page to display by calling:

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#X", { transition: "slideup"} );
```

First best practice/style question:  is this a reasonable way of making jquery navigate thru your page?  (Specifically, does it break some kind of internal jquery rule that might be causing the second problem I will describe shortly?)

This works just fine until I display div C.  If the user hit Show Dialog and then hits Do That on the dialog then function doThat() displays div D which contains a form.

The user enters form data and hits the Save button.  The button executes the function save()  which makes 2 ajax calls.

The 2nd ajax call is done from the success function of the 1st.

As convoluted as that is, it works ok - or at least I get the results back from the 2nd Ajax call.

Second best practice/style question: is there some reason, other than looking weird, that I wouldn't want to make an ajax call from within another ajax call?

The big question is, after the 2nd ajax call returns, why doesn't div D remain on screen?  Instead of remaining (and even though I have NOT hit Back), div D goes away and div A redisplays.  Can anyone explain why?

MOST IMPORTANTLY - can anyone suggest how to prevent it?  I want div D to remain on screen until the user hits Back and then i want div C to display.

More correctly, I want to populate div C with the data returned by the 2nd ajax call and redisplay div C.

Comment: If you `e.preventDefault()` upon submitting the form, the problem will vanish. I would recommend attaching listeners rather than using inline js.

Comment: I agree with Omar. Also, if you don't need the form button to be a type="submit" as you are actually calling a function rather than submitting the form, this will also keep you on page D. Here is a DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/px8ns6br/

Comment: thank you very much, that worked!  i have 3 more questions.  why was e.preventDefault() necessary?  is it necessary on all forms?  lastly, do you mean listeners on the buttons where i have something like href="javascript:doThis();" ?

Comment: @user1126515 Now you've got the answer. Please do some research by yourself to find out what `e.preventDefault()` does, how to attach event listeners using js etc. If you couldn't find anything then ask more questions.